# error while import pytorch module. (The specified module could not be found.)

Tags: python, dll, pytorch

I just newly install python 3.8 via anaconda installer and install pytorch using command

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

when i try to import torch, I got this error message.

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\chunc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\asmjit.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I can see [dll files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s92PY.png) are still in the directory.

I ran Dependency Walker and it gave me [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsnqp.png).

I am with this problem for a day.

What should i do if i want to use PyTorch module?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem, you should check if you installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable, because if you didn't this may lead to the DLL load failure.
Here is a link to download it: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: I think you just saved me hours of my life.

Comment: You also need to restart your system after installing these.

Answer (score 2):

I tried so many different solutions but I couldn't get PyTorch to work on my main conda environment. So finally I created a new environment and installed PyTorch on it; everything worked on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by downgrade PyTorch version to 1.5.1