# PyTorch installed but cannot be loaded when importing

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, anaconda

I am trying to install and import PyTorch on a University server, but when importing I receive the error message

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\asmjit.dll" or one of its dependencies."

I googled and tried all possible solutions from updating to reinstalling. The PyTorch package seems to be installed according to my `pip` command, but I still receive this message. I do not have these issues on my private, but slow laptop. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How did you install PyTorch and how are you running Python?

Comment: I run Python using Jupyter Notebooks (I guess that's what you mean) and I installed PyTorch using the prompt with pip install torch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error while import pytorch module. (The specified module could not be found.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187161/error-while-import-pytorch-module-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: I do not know unfortunately because I am unabled to install anything on the servers, hence I am looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Check if `Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64"` returns some info (change to `x86` if needed). Run this command in a cmd.

Comment: it tells me I have the version 14.0.24212.00 installed. Checking online it seems that the latest version starts with 16. Can I conclude this has to be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As Far as you use anaconda you should use code below instead of pip:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

This link might be helpful :
https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch

If you have trouble , Consider if anaconda added to the path

Comment: I use Windows, I checked the version in pip and it says 1.5.0+cpu. I cannot import the package as I get the mentioned error. How could I check the version used in the code?

Comment: The last version of PyTorch is 1.9.0 . When you want to run a python script You should specify the python interpreter for it.if you use pycharm you can add the PyTorch to the interpreter via pycharm. It may save you from confusing about the python version.If you use the virtual environment You should make sure it is activated and has PyTorch Installed.