# OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, windows-11

While importing torch (`import torch`) I'm facing the following error message:
`OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\jitbackend_test.dll" or one of its dependencies.`

I tried the suggestion from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187161/error-while-import-pytorch-module-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) but without success.

Any ideas how to fix it?

My environment:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
- Windows 11
- Cuda 11.5
- Conda 4.10.3
- Python 3.8.5
- Torch 1.10
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installed (https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)

Comment: I very, very, very much doubt that CUDA 11.5 will be the right version for whatever build of Pytorch you have, but that might not be your only problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, after extensive research, I found a solution.
Someone suggested me to create a new conda environment. And that worked for me!

**Solution:**

1. create new conda env by: `conda create --name new-env`
2. install python: `conda install python=3.8.5`
3. run: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch`
4. test cuda: `import torch; print(torch.version.cuda); print(torch.cuda.is_available())`

Answer (score 3):

reinstalling problematic library (torchaudio) + closing and reopening terminal fixed the issue for me ( on windows )

`python -m pip install --upgrade torchaudio`