# Why do I need to import sympy to import torch 1.12.1

Tags: python, pip, conda, sympy, torch

Until last Wednesday, I could import torch without any issues. Since yesterday, I am getting the following error:

```
>>> import torch  
No sympy found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 1465, in <module>
    from . import _meta_registrations
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_meta_registrations.py", line 7, in <module>
    from torch._decomp import _add_op_to_registry, global_decomposition_table, meta_table
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_decomp\__init__.py", line 169, in <module>
    import torch._decomp.decompositions
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_decomp\decompositions.py", line 10, in <module>
    import torch._prims as prims
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_prims\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from torch._subclasses.fake_tensor import FakeTensor, FakeTensorMode
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_subclasses\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from torch._subclasses.fake_tensor import (
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_subclasses\fake_tensor.py", line 13, in <module>
    from torch._guards import Source
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_guards.py", line 78, in <module>
    class ShapeGuard(NamedTuple):
  File "C:\Users\Marcus Willems\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\_guards.py", line 79, in ShapeGuard
    expr: sympy.Expr
NameError: name 'sympy' is not defined
```

After installing sympy I am getting the following output.

```
Collecting sympy==1.11
  Downloading sympy-1.11-py3-none-any.whl (6.5 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 6.5/6.5 MB 21.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting mpmath>=0.19
  Using cached mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (536 kB)
Installing collected packages: mpmath, sympy
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torch 2.0.1 requires filelock, which is not installed.
flair 0.12.2 requires boto3, which is not installed.
flair 0.12.2 requires gensim>=3.8.0, which is not installed.
flair 0.12.2 requires lxml, which is not installed.
torchvision 0.13.1 requires torch==1.12.1, but you have torch 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.12.1 requires torch==1.12.1, but you have torch 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed mpmath-1.3.0 sympy-1.11
```

Furthermore, I am getting Windows errors like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958526/oserror-winerror-127-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found) and creating a new environment did not work.

I am getting errors connected to torch 2.0.1, however, I do not have it installed on my system. My conda list is as follows:

```
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
altair                    4.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ansicon                   1.89.0                   pypi_0    pypi
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               21.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39h2bbff1b_0
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
base58                    2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py39haa95532_0
black                     22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blessed                   1.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
blinker                   1.4                      pypi_0    pypi
blis                      0.7.7                    pypi_0    pypi
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h2bbff1b_1003
ca-certificates           2022.07.19           haa95532_0
cachetools                4.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
catalogue                 2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.5.18.1              pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.15.0           py39h2bbff1b_1
charset-normalizer        2.0.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
click-log                 0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
commonmark                0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cpuonly                   2.0                           0    pytorch
cryptography              37.0.1           py39h21b164f_0
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cymem                     2.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
de-core-news-sm           3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.5.1            py39hd77b12b_0
decorator                 4.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
distinctiveness           0.14.6                   pypi_0    pypi
en-core-web-lg            3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
en-core-web-sm            3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
enlighten                 1.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
fasttext                  0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.28.3                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
future                    0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
ghp-import                2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
gitdb                     4.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
gitpython                 3.1.24                   pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
humanfriendly             10.0                     pypi_0    pypi
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        4.8.2            py39haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        4.8.2                hd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py39haa95532_1
ipython                   7.29.0           py39hd4e2768_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.0           py39haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jinxed                    1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jsonpickle                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.9.1            py39haa95532_0
jupyterlab-widgets        1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
kiwisolver                1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
langcodes                 3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libdeflate                1.8                  h2bbff1b_5
libpff-python-ratom       20220304                 pypi_0    pypi
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libratom                  0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
libtiff                   4.4.0                h8a3f274_2
libuv                     1.40.0               he774522_0
libwebp                   1.2.4                hbc33d0d_1
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h2bbff1b_1
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
markdown                  3.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1            py39h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mergedeep                 1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h2bbff1b_1000
mkdocs                    1.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs-material           8.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs-material-extensions 1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h277e83a_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hf11a4ad_0
mknotebooks               0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
more-itertools            8.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
murmurhash                1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
mypy-extensions           0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
nb_conda_kernels          2.3.1            py39haa95532_0
nbclient                  0.5.9                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nltk                      3.7                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.4.6            py39haa95532_0
numpy                     1.22.4                   pypi_0    pypi
nxviz                     0.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1q               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
palettable                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.0                      py_0
pathspec                  0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pathy                     0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pbr                       5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.1                     pypi_0    pypi
platformdirs              2.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
plotly                    5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pooch                     1.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prefixed                  0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
preshed                   3.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.8                      py_0
protobuf                  3.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pybind11                  2.10.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydantic                  1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pydeck                    0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyg                       2.1.0           py39_torch_1.12.0_cpu    pyg
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygod                     0.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pymdown-extensions        9.1                      pypi_0    pypi
pympler                   0.9                      pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9            py39haa95532_0
pyreadline3               3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pysimplegui               4.55.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39haa95532_0
python                    3.9.7                h6244533_1
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-dotenv             0.19.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python-louvain            0.16                     pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   1.12.1              py3.9_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-cluster           1.6.0           py39_torch_1.12.0_cpu    pyg
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
pytorch-scatter           2.0.9           py39_torch_1.12.0_cpu    pyg
pytorch-sparse            0.6.15          py39_torch_1.12.0_cpu    pyg
pytorch-spline-conv       1.2.1           py39_torch_1.12.0_cpu    pyg
pytz                      2021.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pytz-deprecation-shim     0.1.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
pyvis                     0.1.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   305              py39h2bbff1b_0
pywinpty                  2.0.10           py39h5da7b33_0
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml-env-tag            0.1                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py39hd77b12b_2
qtconsole                 5.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      1.11.3                   pypi_0    pypi
regex                     2022.4.24                pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rich                      12.5.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ruptures                  1.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-network            0.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
semver                    2.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                62.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools-scm            6.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
simplejson                3.17.6                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
smart-open                5.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
smmap                     5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
spacy                     3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
spacy-legacy              3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
spacy-loggers             1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy                1.4.37                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
srsly                     2.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
stqdm                     0.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
streamlit                 1.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
streamlit-aggrid          0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
streamlit-option-menu     0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
striprtf                  0.0.20                   pypi_0    pypi
tabulate                  0.8.9                    pypi_0    pypi
tenacity                  8.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
thinc                     8.0.17                   pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tomli                     1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
toolz                     0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.12.1                 py39_cpu    pytorch
torchvision               0.13.1                 py39_cpu    pytorch
tornado                   6.1              py39h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.64.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
treelib                   1.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
typer                     0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2021.5                   pypi_0    pypi
tzlocal                   4.1                      pypi_0    pypi
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.26.9                   pypi_0    pypi
validators                0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wasabi                    0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
watchdog                  2.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py39haa95532_1
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py39haa95532_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
xz                        5.2.6                h8cc25b3_0
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.12               h8cc25b3_3
zstd                      1.5.2                h19a0ad4_0
```

I am working on Windows 10, Conda Version 23.1.0. Please let me know if you need additional information and I will happily provide you with them.

I also created a new environment from the project's .yml file and the error still occurs.

Comment: You are doing `import torch` and installing `sympy` in a different shell environment than your Conda environment. You can do `pip install pytorch==1.12.1` in your shell environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could fix the issue and would like to summarize it shortly.

After doing `pip install` as mentioned by @aaron I encountered the same error as described [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/error-loading-caffe2-detectron-ops-dll-in-windows/111995) but the solution given there worked for me as well.

Afterwards, I was still facing `OSError`s connected to different sub-modules from torch, like `torch-scatter`, for example. This is mentioned on pytorch's discussion page on Github: https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/discussions/6981

The solution of uninstalling and installing the corresponding module worked. I had to do this several times but it finally solved itself.

Lessons learned:
`pip install` rather than `conda install`!